# Popen Communicate between processes in different versions

Tags: python, subprocess, pickle, communication, popen

I need to call a different version of python from a main script.  I have been able to use popen to call the script, and am able to get a value returned from it using pickle.  However, I need to send data to the script (not just pass arguments).

```
#getPickel.py

import pickle
import subprocess as sp
p = sp.Popen("py -2 ./sendPickle.py", stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stdin = p.communicate()
results = pickle.loads(stdout)
print 'Returned from send to get: ',results
```

The script that gets called from the above script, and returns a dict.  This script needs to receive data, then process it, then return the dict.

```
#sendPickle.py

import pickle
import sys
#Here should load or read data by the getPickle.py file then next line modify it, then return it
#received = pickle.loads(sys.stdin) # something like this is the goal, but does not work
to_return = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
pickle.dump(to_return, sys.stdout)
```

I have found this sample code that says, "To set up the Popen instance for reading and writing, use a combination of the previous techniques." However, it is not clear to me how this works in two different files, or an external python getting called like my code above.

```
import subprocess
print '\npopen2:'
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat', '-'],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
stdout_value = proc.communicate('through stdin to stdout')[0]
print '\tpass through:', repr(stdout_value)
```

Comment: Why do you need to call a different version of python?

Comment: its calling system python vs the original script running in a box that cannot have libraries installed